# Golang negroni and http.NewServeMux() issue

Tags: http, go, servemux

I am running a server with below code:

```
// Assuming there is no import error
  mux := http.NewServeMux()
  mux.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
  http.Error(w, "File not found", http.StatusNotFound)
  })

  n := negroni.Classic()
  n.Use(negroni.HandlerFunc(bodmas.sum(4,5)))
  n.UseHandler(mux)
  n.Run(":4000" )
```

It works perfectly fine.

But when I wrap `bodmas.sum` with another `http handler` I always get "File not found." The flow does not go to this route.

```
  mux := http.NewServeMux()
  mux.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    http.Error(w, "File not found", http.StatusNotFound)
  })

  n := negroni.Classic()
  n.Use(negroni.HandlerFunc(wrapper.RateLimit(bodmas.sum(4,5),10)))
  n.UseHandler(mux)
  n.Run(":" + cfg.Server.Port)
}
```

`wrapper.RateLimit` is define as below. This works as expected when tested separately:

```
func RateLimit(h resized.HandlerFunc, rate int) (resized.HandlerFunc) {
    :
    :
  // logic here

    rl, _ := ratelimit.NewRateLimiter(rate)

    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, next http.HandlerFunc){
        if rl.Limit(){
            http.Error(w, "Gateway Timeout", http.StatusGatewayTimeout )
        } else {
             next(w, r)
         }
    }
}
```

There is no error.
Any suggestions about this behavior ? 
How to make it work ?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what sure what is the problem with this code, but it appears to be not the  `negorni` way. `negroni` might not behave as expected if we wrap its handler with another `http.Handlerfunc`. So, I modified my code and got the work done by `middleware`.

My current code looks something like as below:

```
         mux := http.NewServeMux()
          mux.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
            http.Error(w, "File not found", http.StatusNotFound)
          })

          n := negroni.Classic()
          n.Use(wrapper.Ratelimit(10))
          n.Use(negroni.HandlerFunc(bodmas.sum(4,5)))
          n.UseHandler(mux)
          n.Run(":4000")
    }
```

`wrapper.go` has  :

```
    type RatelimitStruct struct {
          rate int 
    }

    // A struct that has a ServeHTTP method
    func Ratelimit(rate  int) *RatelimitStruct{
        return &RatelimitStruct{rate}
    }

    func (r *RatelimitStruct) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, next       http.HandlerFunc){
        rl, _ := ratelimit.NewRateLimiter(r.rate)

        if rl.Limit(){
            http.Error(w, "Gateway Timeout", http.StatusGatewayTimeout )
        }

 else {
        next(w, req)
    } 
}
```

Hope it helps someone.